# $watchGroup unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been using $watchGroup to watch a range of fields and trigger a range of functions depending if a particular field has been changed.

I've set up the following [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/F5L7dkwsod7iULKd72Ay?p=preview) to demonstrate the unexpected behaviour I've came across.

```
 $scope.$watchGroup(['first', 'second', 'third'], function(newValues, oldValues)
  {
    var message =
    {
      first: newValues[0],
      second: newValues[1],
      third: newValues[2],
      firstOld: oldValues[0],
      secondOld: oldValues[1],
      thirdOld: oldValues[2]
    };

    if(newValues[0] !== oldValues[0]){
      console.log('First changed')
    }

    if(newValues[1] !== oldValues[1]){
      console.log('Second changed')
    } 

    if(newValues[2] !== oldValues[2]){
      console.log('Third changed')
    }

    $scope.messages.push(message);
  });
```

The scenario involves three watched fields and I'd like to trigger a function depending on which field has changed. I've been using the 'newValues' and 'oldValues' to monitor which field has changed.

The problem I've came across is that if I've changed the "Second" field then go and change the "First" or "Third" field, the "Second" function is triggered as its storing the previous 'newValues' and 'oldValues' which makes it look like the "Second" field has changed as demonstrated in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs7VD.png).

I've highlighted the anomaly in the picture. I'd expect once I started changing the "Third" field, the 'newValues' and 'oldValues' for "Second" to be the same as it isn't the field changing.

I'm aware that I could persist two levels of old values and compare them to get around this however I'd expect it to work as I've described. Any clarification if this is a bug or intended functionality would be appreciated.

The angular documentation for $watchGroup states that watchExpressions is an "Array of expressions that will be individually watched using $watch()". Which makes me think that this isn't intended functionality.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with something I'm working on and would like to be able to tell which watchExpression triggered off the $watchGroup listener function. Would like to hear a solution for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the Angular docs for $watch group and **that it internally uses $watch for each individual expression** I think what you are seeing is the expected behavior

From the docs for $watchGroup,

```
   *    The `newValues` array contains the current values of the `watchExpressions`, with the indexes matching
   *    those of `watchExpression`
   *    and the `oldValues` array contains the previous values of the `watchExpressions`, with the indexes matching
   *    those of `watchExpression`
```

So the new value always has only the latest value and old values contains the previous value.

Secondly, the $watchGroup internally calls the $watch [And what you see is the same behavior for watch]. $watch updates the last value and current value and then calls the listener function only if the current value is different from last value. So in this case, say when you update 'first' expression after 'second' expression, the listener function is not invoked for the 'second' expression and old value is still 'second value'.

If your listener function is really dependent on the which expression has changed, then you are better off using $watch instead of $watchGroup [IMHO, i don't see a performance difference as the $watch is going to be triggered for all expressions]. But if you want call a common handler and pass all new values irrespective of which expression has changed then you could go for $watchGroup.

*All said, it would be still be good if you could post this in angular group and get it confirmed from "horse's mouth" :)*